# Is there a way to add a script tag to all the pages of the BigCommerce store through API?

Tags: javascript, api, bigcommerce

I know there is a [Script API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/scripts.html), but it's in the beta version, and I can use it only if the store in beta version.

Maybe I can add script tag through Stencil framework, or are there other ways?

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically, the only way will be through the Scripts API when it comes out of beta. Prior to the Scripts API release, the process has been for app developers to provide scripts to be  manually copy-pasted into the header or footer as part of the app installation process.

Scripts can be pasted into the Google Tracking code box (under Advanced Settings>Web Analytics in the Control panel) to place the script in the `<head>` or into Storefront>Footer Scripts to place the code in the `<footer>`.

Comment: When you plan to release the Script API from the beta?

Comment: We don't have a firm date yet, but we hope to have it out soon. I'll let you know when I have an ETA.

Comment: @ismakv Wanted to follow up and let you know that the Scripts Manager API is now in general availability.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just using the Store Admin?  If you go to Admin->Storefront->Footer Scripts, there is an area where you can paste in your sitewide scripts.